# How do I use multiple getchar in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I can't find the answer to this problem no matter where I look

```
char input1;
char input2;

printf("Please enter two characters\n");

input1=getchar();
input2=getchar();
printf("The first character you enetered is ");
putchar(input1);
printf("\n");
printf("The second character you enetered is ");
putchar(input2);
printf("\n");

return 0;
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: But what *is* the problem?

Comment: Maybe you expect to see the pressed key immediatelly but you have to enter 2 chars + Enter end then see them both.

Comment: I gues you have faild to get two chars?

Answer (score 3):

You could put getchar in a loop. If the input is a newline or space just continue the loop. This loop terminates once both input variables have been assigned. Now it does not matter if the inputs are consecutive or separated by newlines or spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char input1 = '\0';
    char input2 = '\0';
    int c = 0;

    puts("Please enter two characters");
    while ( ( c = getchar ( ))) {
        if ( c == '\n' || c == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        if ( c == EOF) {
            puts ( "could not get input");
            return 1;
        }
        if ( input1 == '\0') {
            input1 = c;
            continue;
        }
        input2 = c;
        break;
    }
    puts("The first character you enetered is ");
    putchar(input1);
    putchar('\n');
    puts("The second character you enetered is ");
    putchar(input2);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you input a character and hit ENTER, you input newline character too. Trivially, you can fix it using another getchar() to consume the newline:

```
input1=getchar();
getchar();
input2=getchar();
getchar();
```

Or you can input *two* characters at a time.

Also, note that `getchar()` retruns an `int`. So, you want to change the type of `input1` and `input2` to `int` and do an error checks (in case it fails it can return `EOF`).